# gitbash change default directory

Tags: git-bash

I uploaded gitbash to my PC several days ago. However I selected the default directory as C:/users/myusername whenever I open it the default directory is somewhere else than my selected path. What can be causing this and how can I fix?

Comment: How do you launch Git Bash? If you right click a directory and choose "Git Bash Here" then it will (probably) open in that directory. Also, if you have a ~/.bash_profile, see if there is a `cd` (change directory) command in there.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** For how to change your default home directory path on Windows 10, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1190364/how-to-set-home-directory-in-win10/1190369) but note that this may break other applications. To change where Git Bash opens, see my answer below.

By default, Git Bash will go to your home directory set by the environment variables `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

This can be changed in the Git Bash program's properties:

1. Search for "Git Bash" in the start menu
2. Right click to open folder location
3. Right click "Git Bash" and open properties window
4. Remove the `--cd-to-home` flag from the "Target" field
5. Set your desired path in the "Start in" field (you will need admin privileges to change this)

**Before**

[image: Git Bash Properties Window]

**After**

[image: Git Bash Properties Window]

Comment: Thank you! In addition, How do I change my default home directory?

Comment: You might want to see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1190364/how-to-set-home-directory-in-win10/1190369) for how to set your home directory. Setting this may mess up other applications though.

Comment: Worked, but I had to remember to remove my original shortcut from the taskbar and re-add this modified one.